# How can I rewrite this URL with Apache?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I want to be able to access `sitenamehere.com/folder/index?a=something` by visiting `sitenamehere.com/folder/something` in my address bar.

How can I do this?

I've looked into mod rewrite but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` or `httpd.conf`.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Your rule
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/index?a=$2 [L]
```

This assumes you want where `folder` is to be mapped over to where `folder` is in your example. If you want to match the literal `folder`, just replace the first capturing group with it (and add it to the replacement).

Answer (score 3):

`mod_rewrite` is an Apache (web server) extension not related to PHP. You'll want to create a file called `.htaccess` and include the following line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*) /folder/index.php?a=$1
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @Loka: If you knew that, why are you asking about PHP? Do some reading on it, then ask specific questions ;)

Comment: Well I guess I'm a bit tierd. :)

Comment: Apache handles all of your web requests, first checking all of the RewriteRules to search for the actual location of the file. When Apache receives a request for /folder/something you're telling it to actually serve the file from /folder/index.php with the arguments a=something